# Swift. Gaining notification access by pushing a button

Tags: swift, notifications

I'm sure that code inside the func is correct, because it works for launching app, but doesn't work for button how I need it..

I have tried to put notification inside button, but it doesn't work

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    /*
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }*/

    @IBAction func SubscribeButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        // Step 1: Ask for permission
               let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
               center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in

               }
               // Step 2: Create the notification content
               let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
               content.title = "Take your ass off"
               content.body = "Do something!"
               content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default


               //Step 3: Create the notification trigger
               let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(10)
               let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
               let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.init(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

               //Step 4: Create the request
               let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
               let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

               //Step 5: Register the request
               center.add(request) { (error) in
                   //Check the error paramater and handle any errors
        }        
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work
"Variable used within its own initial value"

Comment: Sorry my mistake you need to write `let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 1, to: Date())!`

Comment: If you found answer useful could you mark as accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 1, to: Date())!` it will add notification after a second. However do not try to add more than one for one second. You need to set a minute at least. Otherwise your app will crash.